# Is it bad to call views inside a View in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created 8 different views and i am using all these views inside a view.
So i was wondering before i go any further with this idea. i want to know does it affects performance too badly or not.

Comment: Using views to reference other views is perfectly acceptable. The performance will greatly depend on your code, though.

Comment: as long as the view is not referencing itself it should be fine

Comment: You don't **call** views (they're not "programs" or code) - you select from them.

Comment: To be fair CREATE VIEW is a form of declarative programming.  I'm not sure how off-base it is to describe referencing one as a "call".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, it's fine.  In many cases I personally consider it preferable to writing one view with a giant and difficult to understand definition.  In my opinion, using multiple views allows you to:

1. Encapsulate discrete logic in individual views.
2. Re-use logic in the individual views without having to repeat the logic (eliminating update problems later).
3. Name your logic so that it's easier for the next programmer to understand what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

Views get "compiled" away during execution plan creation. Therefore there is only a very small penalty for using them: The extra time it takes SQL Server to look up the definition. Usually this delay is not measurable.

That means using views for the purposes mentioned by Larry Lustig is perfectly fine and encourage-able.

HOWEVER: Make sure that you do not introduce unnecessary JOINs using this technique. While SQL Server has mechanisms to eliminate unneeded tables from a query it quickly gives up if the query becomes to complex. Executing those additional JOINs can cause a significant slowdown. This is the reason that many companies have a no-view-rule in place.

So: Use views, but make sure to not misuse them.

Answer (score 3):

It's not bad for performance just for being a view. It may add some complexity to maintain, and cause additional consideration when you want to change the schema of the underlying tables. If you were using views and they joined to the same tables, I think that would be less efficient than joining to the table once in one view.

Answer (score 3):

I favour using nested views, with each view encapsulating and naming some cross section of data.

As for performance, it can actually improve performance if the alternative required that same data to be queried multiple times: A nested view is a bit like a temporary table - fired once.

The best, and recommended, way to discover performance implications is to try both options and examine the explain output.

Answer (score 1):

The pure fact of querying a view from within a view does not have any negative performance implications.  It is not different from querying a table from within a view.